# How to maintain the milisecond precision of a SQL datetime(6) when extracting and reinserting with JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, timestamp, mariadb

I need to write a Java program which reads from a MariaBD instance, assembles an instance of a model class, and saves it into a mirror database instance, downstream. The upstream database uses the data type datetime(6), for microsecond precision. I need the field in the downstream database to have the same precision as the upstream database. However, as the data moves through the JDBC code, the last 3 decimal places of precision are lost.

I have experimented with different Java data types (LocalDateTime, Calendar, long) to represent the field while it exists in the Java app, but without success.

Finally, I tried skipping the model class, just to see what would happen, and passed the value from the upstream result set directly into a prepared statement to insert into the downstream (see code example below). Incredibly, that truncated the value to seconds.

What is the secret, please, to maintaining the precision?

```
    try (Connection connection1 = dataSource1.getConnection();
            Connection connection2 = dataSource2.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement selectStmt = connection1.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM foo_upstream");
            PreparedStatement insertStmt = connection2.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO foo_downstream (foo_id, sql_timestamp) VALUES (?, ?)")) {

        try (ResultSet rs = selectStmt.executeQuery()) {

            while(rs.next()) {

                insertStmt.setLong(1, rs.getInt("foo_id"));
                insertStmt.setTimestamp(2, rs.getTimestamp("sql_timestamp"));

                insertStmt.addBatch();
            }
        }

        insertStmt.executeUpdate();
    }
```

[edited the spike code to make it clear that the upstream and downstream are different data sources, which are not guaranteed to have the same time zone settings]

Comment: What about `String`?

Comment: I believe that would work only if the 2 database instances were in the same time zone. They are not. Though, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you select out an expression that coverts the datetime to epoch microseconds, and then similarly insert back an expression? (I forget offhand if the latter is possible.)

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I'm assuming that you mean to use some SQL function to convert the data type as part of the select statement, rather than do all my manipulation in Java code. If I've interpreted incorrectly, please clarify. I'll see what I can do. It may take a bit of time to try it out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant. Good luck!

Comment: I would have expected your code to preserve your microsecond precision. Could this be a bug in your JDBC driver?? As an aside, `Timestamp` is an outdated class, I recommend you use `Instant` or `LocalDateTime` from `java.time` instead (the modern Java date and time API).

Comment: Are both database MariaDB? Which driver are you using (+ its version)?